# Нужна помощь с задачей на Java

Tags: java

Нужна помощь с задачей на Java: есть строка например

```
String s = "1503288168"
```

Нужно получить массив который должен выглядеть так

`{"11","2","3","-","5","6","-","888","-"}`

т.е. в массиве должно быть 9 строк, если в строке s две цифры 1 то и в массиве, в соответствующей строке должно быть две цифры 1 и так далее до 9-ти.

---

Вот что у меня получилось, программа проходит по строке s выбирает необходимые символы, которые заносятся в строку но я не могу собрать из этих строк массив.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s = "1503288168";
   String sp = "1";
   try {
       String p = Z(s, sp);
       System.out.println(Z(s, sp));
   }catch (IllegalStateException ex){
       System.out.println();
   }

}
public static String Z(String s, String sp) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int n = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
        n++;
    }
    return m.group();
    }
```

Comment: На вид должно быть 10 строк, а не 9 (от 0 до 9) + необходиммо, чтобы вы сами попытались и наваяли что-нибудь, за вас с 0ля писать код не станут, вам могут лишь помочь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так?)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new TestClass().stringToValueArray("1503288168")));
}

public String[] stringToValueArray(String input) {
    String[] temp = new String[10];
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int step = -1;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            if ((step = input.indexOf(String.valueOf(i), ++step)) != -1) {
                sb.append(i);
            } else if (sb.length() < 1) {
                sb.append('-');
            }
        } while (step != -1);
        if (sb.length() > 0)
            temp[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**UPD:** Навеял такой алгоритм (ответ @Sanek Zhitnik, за что ему спасибо):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new TestClass().stringToValueArray("1503288168")));
}

private String[] stringToValueArray(String input) {
    String[] result = { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(input.charAt(i));
        int index = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)); 
        result[index] = result[index] == "-" ? sb.toString() : sb.append(result[index]).toString();
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Разъясню **изменения**: метод `stringToValueArray(String input)` один раз проходит по строке (Коротая в своей сути является `private final char value[]` и соответственно доступ к ячейке мы получаем за константное время ) приводим полученный за каждый шаг итерации символ к типу `int`.Затем используя вышеполученное число уже инкрементируем результирующую запись - быстро и эфективно.

Comment: А можно ли сделать так что бы нули в массив не выписывались а только от 1 - 9?

Comment: Да добавьте исключающий фильтр в метод или обрежьте массив полученный в результате работы данного метода

Answer (score 5):

Данный код посчитает количество повторений:

```
int m[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
        m[Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1))]++;
    }
```

А этот сформирует массив:

```
String [] sm = new String [10];
    for (int i = 0; i <m.length ; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int j = 0; j <m[i] ; j++) {
            sb.append(i);
        }
        if (sb.length()==0)
            sb.append("-");
        sm[i]=sb.toString();

    }
```